# Publish statistic from wso2 EI to wso2 Stream Processor

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator, ei

I need to know how is it possible to publish statistics via event publisher from Enteprise Integrator to Stream Processor.

I have following implementation of event publisher on my EI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventPublisher name="MessageFlowStatisticsPublisher"
  statistics="enable" trace="enable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventpublisher">
  <from streamName="org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry" version="1.0.0"/>
  <mapping customMapping="disable" type="wso2event"/>
  <to eventAdapterType="wso2event">
    <property name="username">admin</property>
    <property name="protocol">thrift</property>
    <property name="publishingMode">non-blocking</property>
    <property name="publishTimeout">0</property>
    <property name="receiverURL">tcp://xxx:7611</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="password">xxx</property>
  </to>
</eventPublisher>
```

On Stream Processor I have simple siddhi app for receive data and print them into log as is shown below

```
@App:name("FlowEntryApp")
@App:description("Plan of flow entry")

@source(type='wso2event', @map(type = 'wso2event'))
define stream FlowEntry(compressed bool, tenantId int, messageId string, flowData string);

@sink(type='log', prefix='My flowEntry:')
define stream TestOutputFlowEntry(messageId string, flowData string);

@info(name='FlowEntryOutput')
from FlowEntry
select messageId, flowData
group by messageId
insert into TestOutputFlowEntry;
```

Also I have setted all configuration for publishing statstics as "enable statistic" and "enable trace" for my proxy service. When I invoke my service, eventPublisher send wso2event to SP, this is working correctly. But on the SP side, SP handle error **"No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 present in cache"**

I know, that problem is in siddhi app, that I define stream "FlowEntry" instead of "org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry" but siddhi language doesn't support characters like '.' in stream name.

So I tried to change stream name on EI site, change streamName in eventPublisher to 'FlowEntry' only, also I changed streamName in json file inside eventstream folder but now when I invoke my service, EI will not send any events to SP.

Have anybody idea how to publish org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry stream to SP and then processed it by siddhi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream name can be overridden by using wso2.stream.id element in the source annotation.

```
@source(type='wso2event', wso2.stream.id='org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry', @map(type = 'wso2event'))<br>
define stream FlowEntry(compressed bool, tenantId int, messageId string, flowData string);
```

By using the above source definition, 'FlowEntry' can still be used inside the Siddhi App, while in the thrift server stream id will be defined as 'org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0'.

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick and helpfull reply! This really helped me, now it's working fine. This hint should someone add to official wso2 documentation of Stream Processor or siddhi query language, because official documentantion should be the main article for solving problems.
Once more thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, this is actually mentioned in the siddhi-io-wso2event docs, https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-wso2event/api/latest/

Comment: Oh, my fault, I didn't notice that. Thanks!